E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) | How to fix
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

it show on terminal when i start to install wine
My code to install
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
please some one Helppp me!!! ;-;

simply putting the error message into google presents this solution
